# центровка колонок у флексбокса

Tags: css, flexbox

сейчас блоки которые находятся во флексбоксе центруются.
как сделать что б они прижались к левому краю

```css
.cont {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-height:80px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
    
}
.item{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: #000;
  margin:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

главное условие что б сохранилось направление блоков(flex-direction column)
и при этом они прижимались к левому краю
Вот так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить `.cont` `align-content: flex-start;`

```css
.cont {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-height:80px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.item{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background: #000;
  margin:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```